# Convert a List of objects to a byte array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this struct definition:

```
public struct ChangedByte
{
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

I have created a:

```
List<ChangedByte> testme = new List<ChangedByte>();
```

(and added items to it)

I convert this to an Array:

```
ChangedByte[] alpha = testme.ToArray();
```

I have this function I found with a similar question on SO:

```
byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
byte[] test = StructureToByteArray(alpha);
```

I get the error:

> Type 'new_encoder.Form1+ChangedByte[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

I would like to convert a list of objects into a byte array (and possibly avoid serialization as it tends to bulk up the size of the array)

Can it be done?

ADDITIONAL:

I have tried amending the Struct to this:

```
public struct ChangedByte
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public byte R;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public byte G;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public byte B;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public int x;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public int y;
}
```

but still the same error.

Comment: So, haven't tested it myself, but you might take a look at MarshalAs-Attribute. Here's a very similar question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6666b71c-5dc6-4bcc-8aae-64f406ff3690/sizeof-and-marshalsizeof-not-working-on-struct?forum=csharpgeneral hope it helps

Comment: @Dominik hi, thanks for posting. I gave it a go but same error. It is possible I have not understood the info.. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: LPWStr is for strings, it doesn't make sense to apply it to int or byte fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case since you aren't only converting a struct, but an array of structs, you will need to loop through your array and convert each item.  Use pointer arithmetic to move through your buffer and add the items.

```
public static byte[] StructureArrayToByteArray(ChangedByte[] objs)
{
    int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ChangedByte));
    int len = objs.Length * structSize;
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++ ) {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(objs[i], ptr + i*structSize, true);
    }
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer made sense and I implemented it but I got the same error on this line:          int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ChangedByte));

Comment: Is the error slightly different, e.g. what Type does it say it is this time that is causing the trouble?

Comment: Oh yes I see that error now when I add [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] to the struct.  Without those attributes, I did not get that compile error.  Does it work for you without those attributes or is it not marshalling correctly in that case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your continued interest. This is message: Type 'new_encoder.Form1+ChangedByte' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods:

```
static byte[] ArrayToBytes<T>(T[] array) where T : struct
{
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        int totalLen = array.Length * len;
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(array[i], ptr + i * len, false);
        }
        var bytes = new byte[totalLen];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, totalLen);
        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}

static T[] ArrayFromBytes<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        int count = bytes.Length / len;
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
        T[] array = new T[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(ptr + i * len);
        }
        return array;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

And use them like this:

```
byte[] test = ArrayToBytes(alpha); // serialize
ChangedByte[] alpha2 = ArrayFromBytes<ChangedByte>(test); // deserialize
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I  implemented it and got the same error on this line:   int len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

Comment: Hi,  I get a different error when I remove this attributes on the fields in the Struct, I get an access violation..

Comment: @AndrewSimpson, I tried it with your ChangedByte struct, and it worked fine for me... Try adding the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` attribute to the struct

Comment: Hi - thanks.   I knew I was missing something. Thanks :)

Comment: @Thomas, Good job. I've modified **ArrayFromBytes** method such as  From 'array[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(ptr + i * len);' To 'array[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr + i * len, typeof(T));'